# How to divide long format R dataframe by a factor and put the factor before divided dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm trying to divide a long-formatted dataframe by a factor (e.g. for each subject) and then put the factor (subject) before the data of each one as a label. The simplied dataframe looks like this, columns X and Y are numbers, column subject is factor. The real dataset actually has hundreds of subjects.

```
X <- c(1,1,2,2)
Y <- c(0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.5)
Subject <- as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B"))
M <- tibble(X,Y,Subject) 

> M
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      X     Y Subject
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  
1     1   0.2 A      
2     1   0.3 A      
3     2   1   B      
4     2   0.5 B
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
> M_trans

A
1 0.2
1 0.3
B
2 1
2 0.5
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and it works to output like below, I couldn't find a way to introduce factors as everything in r works in vector format. If you find a better solution, post it for us.

```
X <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
Y <- c(0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.5,0.2,0.9)
Subject <- as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B","C","C"))
M <- tibble(X,Y,Subject) 

unq_subjects <- unique(Subject)

final <- data.frame()
for  (i in 1: length(unique(Subject)))
{
  sub <- unq_subjects[i]
  tmp <- as.data.frame(M %>% filter(Subject == sub) %>%
                         select(-Subject) %>%
                         add_row(X = sub, Y = NA) %>%
                         arrange(desc(X)))     
  final <- union_all(tmp,final)
}

final Output

  X   Y
1 C  NA
2 3 0.2
3 3 0.9
4 B  NA
5 2 1.0
6 2 0.5
7 A  NA
8 1 0.2
9 1 0.3
```

Does it answer your question now?

Comment: Thank you. I got one (posted) but the code is kinda long

Comment: @ShihaoHu: hey I have modified the answer to suit your output, without having to use long code using base R

Comment: Hi, thank you. Your code is more concise. But actually, I have hundreds of "Subjects" (e.g., A, B, C, ...Z) in my dataframe. Is there any way to process them altogether?

Comment: @ShihaoHu I have updated the code to loop through every subject and create a data frame at the end. Hope if helps

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr and tidyr

```
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr) 
M %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  nest()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here I got an inelegant solution worked for myself, inspired by Bertil Baron's answer. I would be happy to got any easier code...

```
trans_output <- function(M){
  M1 <- M %>% 
    group_by(subject) %>%
    nest()
  df <- NULL
  for (i in 1:2)
  {
    output2 <- M1$data[[i]]
    df_sub <- rbind(as.character(M1$subject[[i]]), # subject ID
                    output2) # output data
    idx <- c(1L)
    df_sub <- df_sub %>% 
      mutate(Y = ifelse(row_number() %in% idx, NA, Y)) %>%  # else, stay as Y
      transmute(X = X,
                Y = as.numeric(Y))
    df <- rbind(df, df_sub)
    rm(df_sub)
  }
  return(df)
}

M_trans <- trans_output(M)
```

The output looks like this:

```
> M_trans
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  X         Y
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A      NA  
2 1       0.2
3 2       0.3
4 B      NA  
5 3       1  
6 4       0.5
```